# SecondActivity.class file is not getting linked with intent object showing in red color

Tags: android, android-intent

```
package com.example.admin.assignment2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button secbtn, google;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        secbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondbutton);
        google = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstbutton);

        secbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext().SecondActivity.class);//not taking the SecondActivity.class showing in Red color
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

when a button is clicked it should take to the second activity where "hello world" is printed using textView Just need help in resolving the error

Answer (score 1):

Intent is a class which is used to launch activity. It has some default constructor. one of that is

```
 Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> class)
 //Create an intent for a specific component.
```

Here in packageContext we need to pass current activity name. possible parameter for packageContext is getApplicationContext() or ActivityName.this or if it is fragment pass getActivity(). Parameter for class is NewActivityName.class

In your case,

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

or

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a period, you need to use a comma.

```
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Intent` needs 2 arguments when you want to start a new activity. You were using dot `.` instead of comma `,`

**Instead of:**

```
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext().SecondActivity.class);
```

**Change To:**

```
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
```

Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java) official tutorial for this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the intent, replace (.) to (,) between the context and activity class

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "." you need to use "," So change the line where you declare the intent as

```
Intent newIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try MainActivity instead of getApplicationContext()

MainActivity.this refers to the the current activity (context) where the getApplicationContext() refers to the Application class.

Try

Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(newIntent);